# MySQL Replication - 1 Master - 2 Slaves. Inserting works for One, not the other

Tags: mysql, replication, auto-increment, wamp

I am a Python developer, working with 3 databases, configured in `Master -> slave,slave` style.

Each `slave` has their own application associated with it.

I am not too familiar with database administration as it relates to replication, but I do have a working scenario between the Master, and **one of the slaves**

The first slave stays in synch at all times properly at this time.

The second slave however, **fails on the first insert**

Table creation queries, user creaiton all replicates fine, but when I input any values, **the first slave gets the record, while the second slave** does not.

I tried importing the master DB to the second slave, updates to records will replicate, but new records will not.

My research leads me to believe this is an issue with **autoincrement** but I have not been able to use this to fix the issue. As opposed to a hack and slash method which is not working I figured id ask here.

If there is any more info I can provide, please let me know.

I am on Windows. Using WAMP Server 2.5 (MySQL 5.6.17)

Thanks for reading

EDIT: I am using `binlog_format=mixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your second slave to `server_id = 3` (or depends on you, should be different from 1st slave)

and in mysql of second slave:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='IP Address of Master Server',
MASTER_USER='slave_user2', 
MASTER_PASSWORD='slave_user_password', 
Below lines will need the values from ‘SHOW MASTER STATUS’ in Master Database
MASTER_LOG_FILE='', 
MASTER_LOG_POS=;
```